# Pass template object between functions with a change of type

Tags: c++, templates, casting, type-conversion

I have some large code where I need to use a templated functor with layers of functions that call each other. The problem is that the type changes at various stages. Below is a minimal example of the type conflict problem. Is there a way to call foo from bar so that the functor will have the necessary type?

```
template<class T>
class Functor { // Abstract base class
public:
    virtual T operator() (const T &a, const T &b) = 0;
    virtual ~Functor(){}
}; 

template<class T>
class Add : public Functor<T> {
public:
    T operator() (const T &a, const T &b){ return a+b; }
};

template<class T> 
void foo(Functor<T> *functor, const T& a, T &b) {
    b = (*functor)(a,a);
}

template<class T>
void bar(Functor<T> *functor, const T &a, T &b ) {
    int ai = (int)a;
    int bi = (int)b;

    // will be functor<double> when called 
    foo(functor,ai,bi);   
    b = (T)bi;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Functor<double> *add = new Add<double> ;

    double a = 1.1;
    double b;

    foo(add,a,b); // fine
    bar(add,a,b); // error: conflicting template types
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might drop dynamic polymorphism  and just use static polymorphism:

```
struct Add {
public:
    template<class T>
    T operator() (const T &a, const T &b){ return a+b; }
};

template<typename Functor, typename T>
void foo(Functor* functor, const T& a, T &b) {
    b = (*functor)(a,a);
}

template<typename Functor, typename T>
void bar(Functor* functor, const T &a, T &b ) {
    int ai = (int)a;
    int bi = (int)b;
    foo(functor,ai,bi);
    b = (T)bi;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Add add;

    double a = 1.1;
    double b = 2.2;

    foo(&add,a,b);
    bar(&add,a,b);
}
```

Comment: agree - it's not possible to rebind template types through a polymorphic base class. This is because the virtual function table must be complete and of finite size, whereas rebinding the type of T through templates must be able to generate a theoretically infinite number of new classes.

Comment: Many Thanks! I believe this will do what I need.